# Strange java lambda error in windows but not linux

Tags: java, linux, windows, lambda, javac

I have a small program that uses a few lambda expressions for events.  This compiled and ran perfectly on my linux machine, but in windows I get an 'Illegal Start Of Expression Error.'  Should I be writing this differently?  This is a snippet showing the structure.  The label in the error message is pointing at 'e ->' when it gives this error.  Again, this compiled and ran as expected in linux using java version 1.8.0_77.  Thanks for your help.  I used the same java version in Windows.

```
rdoChecking.addActionListener(e -> {
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("disable")){
            rdoChecking.setSelected(false);
            rdoSavings.setSelected(true);
        }else {
            rdoChecking.setSelected(true);
            rdoSavings.setSelected(false);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Are you using an IDE?

Comment: Yes and no.  I originally wrote it in intellij but, as always,  I did a separate compilation from the command line using javac to double check for errors.  In linux - no errors; in windows - many errors.

Comment: What do you get with `javac -version`? e.g. I get in Windows: `javac 1.8.0_77`.

Comment: Also, I did create an executable jar file from this in linux and was able to run it on windows 10 without error.  Windows will run it, it just won't compile it.

Comment: @PaulVargas Same as you.  I updated both machines just to be sure.

Comment: Try with `-encoding utf8`. e.g. `javac -encoding utf8 x.java`. Some Windows uses Cp1252 as default encoding. `javac` gets the default encoding from the OS.

Comment: @PaulVargas  Tried it to no avail.  I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this fully answers my question but I was able to get this to work without changing any code.  What I did was copy and past the code into a new netbeans project on windows one class at a time and recompiled from there.  From within netbeans, it compiles without error, but I still get the same errors wen trying to compile from command line.

Comment: I am more than willing to pass the full code to anyone who would like to verify this.  It isn't a very long program, but as it is a school assignment, I think it is best not to post it in full here.  Feel free to message me if you want to try to reproduce the errors yourself.